Problem with Subform updating half way through typing the contents of a text box and then it deletes the text already typed
Please see below. I have a continuos form that I have added a command button to. The command button opens a pop form. The form contains a subform. I have set it so that the user can not edit or delete the comments once he has made them. I ran into a problem that Access updates from time to time and if you leave the typing midpoint in the Chat box then it save the record and thus locks the user out, due to the fact that they dont have the option to edit. I only want them to add records. Parent and Child links are established. I want the details of the client on the top so that the person can see who they are talking to. I also have the subform within this that shows all the previous calls for this visit to the workshop.
I have included this code to stop it from updating.
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.Dirty = True And (ChatText = Null Or Outcome = Null Or Called = False Or DateTimeCalled = Null) Then
Cancel = True
End If
End Su

b
The problem that I am having is that Access seems to want to update but then it reads the code but doesnt. This then highlights the text and when you carry on typing it deletes the highlighted text.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Still a newbie.
Sheet with records
Pic 1
Pic 2strong text
Someone suggested I use unbound forms but I am struggling as a newbie. VBA is hurting me..:)
Here is the code:
Private Sub CallMade_Click()
Dim err As Integer
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb

'Check that all fields are filled in
txtChat.SetFocus
If txtChat.Text = "" Then
err = err + 1
MsgBox "Please fill in the Chat!" & err
End If

txtOutcome.SetFocus
If txtOutcome.Text = "" Then
err = err + 1
MsgBox "Please fill in the Outcome!"
End If

'if no errors insert data
If err < 1 Then

Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("CustChats", Options:=dbAppendOnly)
rec.AddNew
rec("Chattext") = Me.txtChat
rec("Outcome") = Me.txtOutcome
rec("DateTimeCalled") = Now()
rec("RegNo") = Me.RegNo
rec("DateofService") = Me.DateofService
rec("Called") = True
rec.Update

rec.Close
db.Close
End If


End Sub

But I keep getting a Type mismatch error from the db.openrecordset command line. Not sure where to from here.
To note: The front end and the back end are split as there are many users (50)

Use unbound form to add comment(s).

I have tried using unbound from but struggling to get it to write to the table. Front end and backend are split. Please see edited question

The CallMade_Click code seems OK and should work (though it could be simpler). The mismatch error on the db.OpenRecordset should not occur because rec is declared as recordset, which is correct. Have you by any chance added a reference to the ADO library and set its priority over the Access Database Engine ?

Thanks Shahram. Much appreciated you have sent me in the right direction.

Glad to help. Please accept your answer as the solution. This helps other people with the same problem find the answer.

The corrected code below has sorted out the problem.
Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/12056172/shahram-alemzadeh
Private Sub CallMade_Click()
Dim err As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

'Check that all fields are filled in
txtChat.SetFocus
If txtChat.Text = "" Then
err = err + 1
MsgBox "Please fill in the Chat Box!"
End If

RegNo.SetFocus
If RegNo.Text = "" Then
err = err + 1
MsgBox "This Customer has no Reg!!!"
End If


txtOutcome.SetFocus
If txtOutcome.Text = "" Then
err = err + 1
MsgBox "Please fill in the Outcome!"
End If

'if no errors insert data
If err < 1 Then



Dim Msg, Style, Response
    Msg = "Are you sure you want to Log this call?"
    Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton1
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style)
    If Response = vbYes Then    ' User chose Yes.
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("CustChats", dbOpenDynaset)
        rst.AddNew
        rst!ChatText = Me.txtChat
        rst!Outcome = Me.txtOutcome
        rst!DateTimeCalled = Now()
        rst!RegNo = Me.RegNo
        rst!DateofService = Me.DateofService
        rst!Called = True
        rst.Update
        rst.MoveLast
        rst.MoveFirst
        rst.Close
        
        
        
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing

        MsgBox "Call Logged!", vbInformation
        Me.txtChat = ""
        Me.txtOutcome = ""
                   
        Else    ' User chose No.
            MsgBox "You have not logged this call!"
    End If


End If


End Sub

